# Json to provide class name path

Tags: java, json

When I used org.json version 20090211 I would have Java pojo:

```
class Person {
   private String name;
   private int age;

   //getters and setters


}
```

Using json I would put in main:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(person, true);
   System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

the output:

```
   {"name":"John","age":30,"class":"class com.Person"}
```

I need to update this library. With the updated library it only has:

```
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(person);  //without true
```

Now the output is:

```
  {"name":"John","age":30}
```

I am missing the class field. How can I get this field back?

Comment: What was the parameter you set to `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could e. g. create your JSONObjects by

```
new JSONObject(person).put("class", Person.class)
```

Perhaps, you could use a factory method like

```
public static JSONObject newJSONObject(Object pojo) {
    return new JSONObject(pojo).put("class", pojo.getClass());
}
```

And, of course, you can modify the library itself.